# $N=1$ and $N=2$ supersymmetry for non-relativistic electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, electrons, supersymmetry

I have been following Fred Cooper's *Supersymmetry in Quantum Mechanics* and I am currently on pages 63/64 where I have now derived the Pauli-Hamiltonian for a non-relativistic electron in an external field.

$$H=\frac{1}{2m}(\overrightarrow{p}+\frac{e}{c}\overrightarrow{A})^2+\frac{g}{2}\frac{e\hbar}{2mc}\overrightarrow{B} \cdot \overrightarrow{\sigma}\tag{5.16}$$

Where the $\frac{g}{2}\frac{e\hbar}{2mc}\overrightarrow{B} \cdot \overrightarrow{\sigma}$ is the result of us imagining  an electron in a purely magnetic field. Cooper then states that $g=2$ and so gives $N=1$ supersymmetry.

He then finds the resultant supercharge

$$Q_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4m}}(\overrightarrow{p}+\frac{e}{c}\overrightarrow{A}) \cdot \overrightarrow{\sigma}.\tag { 5.17}$$

1. My first questions is how can I show that his claim that $g=2$ implied $N=1$ supersymmetry, mathematically?

He then states when the magnetic field is perpendicular to the electrons motion we have $N=2$ supersymmetry and the introduction of a complex supercharge.

2. Again how do I show that the now perpendicular magnetic field gives $N=2$ supersymmetry, mathematically?

Comment: Didn't you ask [this question, 318269](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/318269/supercharges-for-n-1-supersymmetry-of-a-super-hamiltonian) 2 weeks ago, and accept the answer? Do you have trouble resolving Pauli matrices as per the identity I am steering you to, below?

Comment: It's actually a different question if you read it properly I earlier asked how Cooper arrived at his solution for the Supercharge and this question refers to understanding how the different situations give different values for N in supersymmetry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both answers are answered explicitly in Cooper, Khare, and Sukhatme,"Supersymmetry and quantum mechanics." Physics Reports 251.5-6 (1995): 267-385, eqns (402-404), without excessive nomenclature stretches contrasting N=1 & 2. But since you wish to stick to their *book*, just heed their exhortation to prove your (5.18), $H=2 Q_1^2$.

Just resolve the product of the Pauli matrices, as you know it, by inspection,
$$
 \frac{2}{4m}\left((\overrightarrow{p}+\frac{e}{c}\overrightarrow{A}) \cdot \overrightarrow{\sigma}\right)^2=\frac{2}{4m} \left ( (\vec{p}+e\vec{A}/c)\cdot(\vec{p}+e\vec{A}/c) + \frac{ie\hbar}{ic} (\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A}) \cdot \vec{\sigma} ) \right )=H ~,
$$ 
where the r.h.side is strictly your Hamiltonian (5.16) with *g* =2, ***not any g***.

Consequently, $\{Q_1,Q_1\}=H$, supersymmetry, and, a fortiori, a symmetry of the hamiltonian,  $[Q_1,\{Q_1,Q_1\} ]=0$, I hope you can see by inspection.

The second part of the exercise, (5.20-5.24) is also straightforward, something you can do following this, always utilizing the [standard Pauli matrix feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Relation_to_dot_and_cross_product). Alert, however: In a breathtakingly unfortunate notation, on the Landau orbit plane, your $Q_1$ here has morphed to that book's $Q^2$ of (5.23), where the "2" is now a new superscript index supplanting the subscript 1, and *not* a power! Manipulating the Pauli matrix commutators, nevertheless, is trivial.

For example, for the off-diagonal piece of (5.24), defining $\Pi_i\equiv p_i+eA_i/c$, by inspection,
$$
2\{ Q^1,Q^2\}= \{ (-\Pi_y \sigma _x + \Pi_x \sigma_y ) ,(\Pi_x \sigma_x+\Pi_y \sigma_y)  \}\\ = i\sigma_z (-\Pi_y^2 + \Pi_x^2 +\Pi_y^2 - \Pi_x^2) + 1\!\!1 (-\Pi_y \Pi_x -\Pi_x \Pi_y +\Pi_x \Pi_y +\Pi_y \Pi_x  )=0 ~,
$$
etc... It's really straightforward, no?

Comment: So how do you show N=2 supersymmetry without knowing the supercharge ? so using the information that the magnetic field is perpendicular to the motion of the electron

Comment: He shows you that for $\Pi_z=0$ the hamiltonian reduces to what he gives, ***observes*** there is an extra supercharge symmetry, $Q^1$ over and above the one you had, $Q^2$, observes these two anti commute but also square to the same hamiltonian, and thus confirms they are both conserved (super)symmetries.

Comment: You do appreciate, don't you that *g≠2* is a red herring: it's *never* used in that section (or book) for anything. He might have set *g=2* from the start to spare you confusion. Essentially, this is the only case he considers, because it is the only case he *can* consider if he wants supersymmetries. That's why I sent you to the PhysRepts article, which is more concise and functional.

Comment: yes I am aware that g can only equal 2